# Does lightning-input-field automatically respect field level security (FLS) from profile/permission sets?

Tags: lightning-web-components, profile, permission-sets, lightning-inputfield, fls

A strength of Visualforce's `apex:inputField` is that it automatically respects the view/edit permissions that come from the profile/permission sets for both the object and the fields.

I'm assuming Lightning Web Component's `lightning-input-field` incorporates that mechanism too, but haven't found confirmation of that by Googling. Does it?

Comment: I would be surprised if it didn't since it is for supporting field input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lightning-record-edit-form supports field-level security that turns out that lightning-input-field also supports FLS. Didn't find any documentation for the lightning-input-field.

Reference - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation

Enclosing an image for a quick look-
[image]

ADD ON - I found a salesforce developer's blog stating for lightning:inputField - https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/01/spring-18-developers-build-secure-interactive-forms-faster.html

[image]

Comment: This is the question on LWC, not aura base component

Comment: Hi @SantanuBoral, I'm under the impression that e.g. `lightning:inputField` and `lighting-input-field` are APIs into the same underlying logic now. Is that not the case?